# PowerBI Pro Contoso Sales for PowerBI not enough memory error

Tags: powerbi

I am just starting on PowerBI and working through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-quickstart-learn-dax-basics. My version of PowerBI Pro is Version: 2.97.861.0 64-bit (September 2021) and creating the calculated field

```
Previous Quarter Sales = CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[SalesAmount]), PREVIOUSQUARTER(Calendar[DateKey]))
```

produces an error : There's not enough memory to complete this operation. Please try again later when there may be more memory available.

I have tried changing the available memory in Options/Data Load/Data Cache Management Options/Maximum Allowed to 8192MB and Q&A Cache Options to 8192 MB but still get the error.

Any advice?

Comment: Do you have 4G of RAM? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/fundamentals/desktop-get-the-desktop#minimum-requirements

Comment: I have 8.00 GB with 7.88 GB usable

Comment: strange error. Is there a link between the calendar table and sales table?